# Is $x\cdot f(x)$ quasiconvex for $x>0$, if $f(x)$ is monotonically decreasing, convex, and positive?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization

### Original question

Given $f(x):\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}^+$, which is monotonically decreasing and convex. Then define a function $g(x) = xf(x)$, I am wondering whether $g(x)$ is quasiconvex for $x>0$.

I try some simple functions, such as $f(x)=x^{-a},\,a>0$, we can see $g(x)=x f(x) = x^{1-a}$, which is always quasiconvex for arbitrary $a>0$.

The quasiconvex is defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiconvex_function).

Any counter-example is helpful.

### Current Attempt

Denote $f\left(x\right) = \sum_i a_i x^{b_i}$, where $a_i \ge 0$ and $b_i\le 0$, which is monotonically decreasing, convex, and positive. Thus $g\left(x\right) = \sum_i a_i x^{c_i}$, where $c_i = b_i +1$.

Then the problem becomes to prove whether $\sum_i a_i x^{c_i}$ is quasiconvex.

(Additional question: is such $f\left(x\right)= \sum_i a_i x^{b_i}$ can represent all monotonically decreasing, convex, and positive functions?)

This question is also asked in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4344140/468437).

### Answer of the original question

No, $x\cdot f(x)$ is not quasiconvex for $x>0$, if we just know $f(x)$ is monotonically decreasing, convex, and positive? The counter-example is $f(x) = e^{-x}$.

In addition, the claim that there is at most zero-point is also not true. The counter-example is $f(x) = (1/x)*(10+sen(x)*e^{-x})$.

Very thanks for SaúlRodríguezMartín's help.

### Extended question

Since there are many cases shown $g(x)$ is quasiconvex or quasiconcave. Thus, the extended question is given $f(x)$ is monotonically decreasing, convex, and positive, under what conditions, $g(x)$ is quasiconvex or quasiconcave?

For example, if $f(x)$ is the combination of power functions, $g(x)$ is quasiconvex; if $f(x)$ is the combination of expotential functions, $g(x)$ is quasiconcave. What is core that dominates such the difference?

Comment: $f(x)=e^{-x}$‏‏‏‎ ‎

Comment: @SaúlRodríguezMartín Thanks for your answer. It is a very nice counter-example.

Comment: @SaúlRodríguezMartín How about the claim that the first-order derivative of $g\left(t\right)$ only has one zero-point. (There is no basis, just my expectations.)

Comment: That would also be false, you can take $f(x)=(1/x)*(10+sen(x)*e^{-x})$ and then $g'(t)$ has infinitely many zeros.

Comment: @SaúlRodríguezMartín. Thanks for your answer. Again, it is a nice counter-example. How do you find such genius functions? Seems you are very familiar with the basic functions, including their limits, derivatives, and so on.

Comment: It was ad hoc, I just wanted some function very close to $1/x$ (close enough to be decreasing and have positive second derivative) but such that it crosses the graph of $1/x$ infinitely many times so $x\cdot f(x)$ has infinite maximums

Comment: @SaúlRodríguezMartín. Thanks again. It is very helpful.